# How to find the left and right children of root in Leonardo heap?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, smoothsort

According to [this article](http://www.keithschwarz.com/smoothsort/), 
The root of the tree is at position L(k) - 1.
The root of the Ltk-1 subtree is at position L(k - 1) - 1.
The root of the Ltk-2 subtree is at position L(k) - 2.

Can someone please help me understand this?? I am trying to implement smoothsort.

Answer (score 2):

Let's imagine you have a Leonardo heap of order k stored in an array, and you recursively do the layout so that you always lay out the bigger subtree, then the smaller subtree, then the root node. That means that there's going to be a total of L(k) nodes in the array, in positions numbered 0, 1, 2, 3..., L(k) - 1. It's going to look something like this:

```
+---------------------------+----------------------+------+
|    Tree of order k - 1    | Tree of order k - 2  | root |
+---------------------------+----------------------+------+
```

Notice that the root comes last, so it's at position L(k) - 1 because we're using zero-indexing.

So where are the two subtrees? Well, the subtree of order k - 2 is immediately before the root node. It's laid out in a way where its root is to the far right. So to find its root, we go to the root of the whole tree (position L(k) - 1) and back up one step to get to position L(k) - 2.

What about the subtree of order k - 1? Well, notice that it's comfortably at the front of our representation. Its root node is going to be at the end of that block, which is at position L(k - 1) - 1 (analogously to how our larger tree of order k has its root at position L(k) - 1.)

Hope you enjoyed my article! :-)

Comment: Thank you..I understand it a little better now